# R Splitting one column into two, when delimiter is '..'

Tags: regex, r

I have a data frame that looks like this:

```
     X1                     X3
1: thrL               190..255
2: thrA              337..2799
3: thrB             2801..3733
4: thrC             3734..5020
5: yaaX             5234..5530
6: yaaA complement(5683..6459)
7: yaaJ complement(6529..7959)
```

I am struggling to separate this dataframe into three columns using the `..` as a separator. I've tried other solutions on similar posts such as `splitstackshape` and `gsub`, however none have really worked because those are for when the delimiters are not wildcard values like periods.

```
     X1   X2   X3  X4
1: thrL  190  255   f
2: thrA  337 2799   f
3: thrB 2801 3733   f
4: thrC 3734 5020   f
5: yaaX 5234 5530   f
6: yaaA 5683 6459   r
7: yaaJ 6529 7959   r
```

This is what I'm trying right now

```
concat.split.multiple(i, "X3", "\\.\\.")
```

Any suggestions?

Thanks in advance

Comment: And in the case of the `complement(1234..5678)`, you just want to ignore the 'complement'?

Comment: I edited my desired output to make it clearer, for the rows that have complements, another row X4 could be added

Comment: `with(dd, cbind(X1, read.table(text=gsub('\\D',' ', X3))))`

Comment: updated with your new column `with(dd, cbind(X1, read.table(text=gsub('\\D',' ', X3)), X4 = c('f','r')[grepl('comp', X3) + 1L]))`

Comment: @rawr that answer is very slick :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `dplyr` and `tidyr`:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
df %>%
   mutate(X4=ifelse(grepl("complement", X3), "f", "r")) %>% 
   mutate(X3=gsub("[a-z()]", "", X3)) %>%
   separate(X3, into=c("X2", "X3"), sep="\\.\\.")
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a base R solution.
Use `fixed=T` in your `strsplit` to split on a literal dot rather than dot as a wildcard. You can use (e.g.) `grepl` to detect the "complement".

e.g.

```
# reproducible example
set.seed(1)
mydf <- data.frame(X1=letters[1:7], X3=paste0(sample(100, 7), '..', sample(100, 7)), stringsAsFactors=F)
mydf$X3[6:7] <- paste0('complement(', mydf$X3[6:7], ')')

#   X1                 X3
# 1  a             27..67
# 2  b             37..63
# 3  c              57..7
# 4  d             89..20
# 5  e             20..17
# 6  f complement(86..66)
# 7  g complement(97..37)
```

Detecting `complement(..)`:

```
mydf$X4 <- ifelse(grepl('complement\\(', mydf$X3), 'r', 'f')
```

Now extracting just the "number..number" bit and splitting:

```
# extract just "number..number", ignoring all else.
tmp <- gsub('^.*?([0-9]+\\.\\.[0-9]+).*$', '\\1', as.character(mydf$X3))
# split. use fixed=T
tmp <- strsplit(tmp, '..', fixed=T)
# extract the splits, convert to numeric
mydf$X2 <- as.numeric(vapply(tmp, '[[', i=1, 'template'))
mydf$X3 <- as.numeric(vapply(tmp, '[[', i=2, 'template'))
# columns not in order, but you know how to fix that.
#   X1 X3 X4 X2
# 1  a 67  f 27
# 2  b 63  f 37
# 3  c  7  f 57
# 4  d 20  f 89
# 5  e 17  f 20
# 6  f 66  r 86
# 7  g 37  r 97
```